# Xcode check error to manage event

Tags: xcode, events, null, ekevent

I have this method to add an event to iOS calendar:

```
-(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender
{
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = nome;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];

    event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startdate];
    event.endDate = [formatter dateFromString:enddate];
    event.allDay = TRUE;

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%@", err);
    [formatter release];

}
```

I would like to test *err to pop up an alert view if the registration has been done successfully.

If it is *err is null: is it correct? If *err=null I have to pop up the alert view.
Can anybody confirm it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is easily done as [`EKEventStore`'s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) method `- (BOOL)saveEvent:(EKEvent *)event span:(EKSpan)span error:(NSError **)error` actually returns a YES or NO value depending on the result of the save.

So you could do something like:

```
if (![eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err])
{
    // code for event not saved
} else {
    // code for event saved
}
```